# While doing url encoding, the std::regex_replace doesn't work properly for character "+"

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-regex

Following is the code snippet, the regex_replace dosn't work properly for character "+", I should not use special handling for the characters, but it should work properly.

```
/*All headerfiles are available.*/



std::string charToHex(unsigned char c, bool bUpperCase);
std::string urlEncode(const std::string& toEncode, bool bEncodeForwardSlash);
std::string getEncodedUrl(const std::string& url){
std::string bktObjKey = "";

std::string urlEnc = url;

boost::regex expression("^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#:]*)(:\\d+)?)?([^?#]*)((\\?[^#]*))?(#(.*))?");

std::string::const_iterator start=url.begin(), end = url.end();
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
if (regex_search(url.begin(), url.end(), what, expression, flags)) {
  std::cout<<"Matched"<<std::endl;
  bktObjKey.insert(bktObjKey.begin(), what[6].first, what[6].second);

  std::regex fobj(bktObjKey);
  /*std::string fobj = bktObjKey;*/

  /*auto pos = url.find(bktObjKey);*/
  bktObjKey = urlEncode(bktObjKey, false);
  std::cout<<"bktObjKey :"<<bktObjKey.c_str()<<" urlEnc: "<<urlEnc.c_str()<<std::endl;

  urlEnc = std::regex_replace(url, fobj, bktObjKey);
  std::cout<<" urlEnc: "<<urlEnc.c_str()<<std::endl;
}
  return urlEnc;
}
std::string urlEncode(const std::string& toEncode, bool bEncodeForwardSlash)  {
  std::ostringstream out;

  std::cout<<"inside encode"<<std::endl;
  for(std::string::size_type i=0; i < toEncode.length(); ++i) {
    char ch = toEncode.at(i);
    if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ||
        (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ||
        (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') ||
        (ch == '_' || ch == '-' || ch == '~' || ch == '.') ||
        (ch == '/' && !bEncodeForwardSlash)) {
      out << ch;
      std::cout<<out.str()<<" Is not coded to HEX"<<std::endl;
    }
    else {
      out << "%" <<  charToHex(ch, true);
      std::cout<<out.str()<<" Is coded to HEX"<<std::endl;
    }
  }
  std::cout<<"Return :"<<out.str()<<std::endl;
  return out.str();
}

std::string charToHex(unsigned char c, bool bUpperCase) {
  short i = c;
  std::stringstream s;
  s << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << i;
  return s.str();
}

int main() {

std::string url1 ="http://10.130.0.36/rbkt10/+";
std::string out1 = getEncodedUrl(url1);
std::cout<<"Encoded URL1=:"<<out1<<std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
Encoded URL1=:http://10.130.0.36/rbkt10/%2b+

So the out put becomes "++". It should be only "+". How can I make it work perfectly?

Comment: Code is for humans to read. Formatting matters

Answer (score 4):

1. You're interpreting the original string as a regex. `+` is special in regex¹.

   You should simply use `std::string::replace` because you don't need regex replace functionality:

   ```
   boost::smatch what;
   if (regex_search(url.cbegin(), url.cend(), what, expression)) {
       boost::ssub_match query = what[6];
       url.replace(query.first, query.second, urlEncode(query.str(), false));
   }
   ```
2. Complicated, scattered code like this: 
   [image] could simply be:

   ```
   std::string bktObjKey = what[6].str();
   ```
3. Complicated loop

   ```
   for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < toEncode.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = toEncode.at(i);
   ```

   Could just be

   ```
   for (char ch : toEncode) {
   ```
4. `charToHex` creates a new 2-char string everytime, using another stringstream everytime, copying the result out of the stringstream etc. Instead, just write to the stringstream you have and avoid all the inefficiency:

   ```
   void writeHex(std::ostream& os, unsigned char c, bool uppercase) {
       os << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;
       if (uppercase) 
           os << std::uppercase;
       os << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c);
   }
   ```

   > Note this also fixes the fact that you forgot to use `bUppercase`
5. Look at `<cctype>` for help classifying characters.
6. Use raw literals to write

   ```
   boost::regex expression("^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#:]*)(:\\d+)?)?([^?#]*)((\\?[^#]*))?(#(.*))?");
   ```

   instead as:

   ```
   boost::regex expression(R"(^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#:]*)(:\d+)?)?([^?#]*)((\?[^#]*))?(#(.*))?)");
   ```

   (no need to doubly escape `\d` and `\?`)
7. Either drop all the redundant sub-groups

   ```
   boost::regex expression(R"(^([^:/?#]+:)?(//[^/?#:]*(:\d+)?)?[^?#]*(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?)");
   ```

   OR make them maintainable and useful²:

   ```
   boost::regex uri_regex(
       R"(^((?<scheme>[^:/?#]+):)?)"
       R"((?<authority>//(\?<host>[^/?#:]*)(:(?<port>\d+))?)?)"
       R"((?<path>[^?#]*))"
       R"((\?(?<query>([^#]*)))?)"
       R"((#(?<fragment>.*))?)");
   ```
8. Now that you have access to logical components of the URI, apply it to know better when and where to encode:

   ```
       std::string escaped = 
          what["scheme"].str() + 
          what["authority"].str() +
          urlEncode(what["path"].str(), false);

       if (query.matched) {
           escaped += '?';
           escaped.append(urlEncode(query, true));
       }

       if (fragment.matched) {
           escaped += '#';
           escaped.append(urlEncode(fragment, true));
       }
   ```
9. Make an overload of `urlEncode` that takes an existing ostream reference instead of always creating your own:

   ```
   std::ostringstream out;
   out << what["scheme"] << what["authority"];
   urlEncode(out, what["path"], false);

   if (query.matched)
       urlEncode(out << '?', query, true);

   if (fragment.matched)
       urlEncode(out << '#', fragment, true);
   ```

### Code After Review

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2fd69378808a754)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void writeHex(std::ostream& os, unsigned char c, bool uppercase) {
    os << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;
    if (uppercase) 
        os << std::uppercase;
    os << '%' << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c);
}

void urlEncode(std::ostream& os, const std::string &toEncode, bool bEncodeForwardSlash) {
    auto is_safe = [=](uint8_t ch) {
        return std::isalnum(ch) ||
            (ch == '/' && !bEncodeForwardSlash) ||
            std::strchr("_-~.", ch);
    };

    for (char ch : toEncode) {
        if (is_safe(ch))
            os << ch;
        else
            writeHex(os, ch, true);
    }
}

std::string urlEncode(const std::string &toEncode, bool bEncodeForwardSlash) {
    std::ostringstream out;
    urlEncode(out, toEncode, bEncodeForwardSlash);
    return out.str();
}

std::string getEncodedUrl(std::string url) {

    boost::regex uri_regex(
        R"(^((?<scheme>[^:/?#]+):)?)"
        R"((?<authority>//(\?<host>[^/?#:]*)(:(?<port>\d+))?)?)"
        R"((?<path>[^?#]*))"
        R"((\?(?<query>([^#]*)))?)"
        R"((#(?<fragment>.*))?)");

    boost::match_results<std::string::iterator> what;
    //boost::smatch what;
    if (regex_search(url.begin(), url.end(), what, uri_regex)) {
        auto& full     = what[0];
        auto& query    = what["query"];
        auto& fragment = what["fragment"];

        std::ostringstream out;
        out << what["scheme"] << what["authority"];
        urlEncode(out, what["path"], false);

        if (query.matched)
            urlEncode(out << '?', query, true);

        if (fragment.matched)
            urlEncode(out << '#', fragment, true);

        url.replace(full.begin(), full.end(), out.str());
    }
    return url;
}

int main() {
    for (std::string url : { 
            "http://10.130.0.36/rbkt10/+",
            "//10.130.0.36/rbkt10/+",
            "//localhost:443/rbkt10/+",
            "https:/rbkt10/+",
            "https:/rbkt10/+?in_params='please do escape / (forward slash)'&more#also=in/fragment",
            "match inside text http://10.130.0.36/rbkt10/+ is a bit fuzzy",
          }) {
        std::cout << "Encoded URL: " << getEncodedUrl(url) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Encoded URL: http//10.130.0.36/rbkt10/%2B
Encoded URL: //10.130.0.36/rbkt10/%2B
Encoded URL: //localhost%3A443/rbkt10/%2B
Encoded URL: https/rbkt10/%2B
Encoded URL: https/rbkt10/%2B?in_params%3D%27please%20do%20escape%20%2F%20%28forward%20slash%29%27%26more#also%3Din%2Ffragment
Encoded URL: match inside text http//10.130.0.36/rbkt10/%2B%20is%20a%20bit%20fuzzy
```

### CAUTION

Notice that the code STILL doesn't adhere to the specs:

> [image]

This is why you use a library instead.

---

¹ (This causes + to be left from the input. It's not "repeated", it's just not replaced because `/+` means 1 or more `/`).

² See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax